# after running the command npm install -g @angular\cli i receive an npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface

I initially used a computer running windows 10 and also on another computer that runs windows 8.1 but, I still receive the same message on both computers. The error log is:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@angular\cli" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

The node and npm versions are 8.2.1 and 5.3.0 respectively.

When I run the command on git bash I receive a different error message. The error log is:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@angularcli": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

Comment: Try character / not \

Answer (score 14):

Your command is wrong:

It's `@angular/cli` with a forward slash not `@angular\cli`

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

In order to install angular-cli on windows use

`npm install -g @angular/cli` in place of `npm install –g @angular-cli`

Comment: `npm i @angular` will also give this error. So it's not just a slash